# Как удалить/обнулить src в теге IMG через JS?

Tags: javascript

Как обнулить или убрать из тега `IMG` атрибут `SRC` через JS?

по теории, что это убирает:

```
servicesSite.innerHTML = "";
```

Подумал, что это также работает, но нет:

```
servicesIco.src = '';
```

То есть у меня есть функция, которая добавляет тег SRC с массива:

```
 let S_NAMES = [
    {site: 'img/logo.svg'},
    {site: 'img/logo-2.svg'},
]
```

Он просто напросто добавляет его к прошлому `SRC` и картинка на второй раз при заходе не видна, потому что в `SRC` белеберда, и поэтому хочу как-то при нажатии на кнопку удалять из `src` или само `src` из тега `IMG`.

Я начинающий.

Comment: Значит в процессе что-то не так делали) `img.src = ""; img.setAttribute('src', ""); img.removeAttribute("");` — работают все варанты. Хоть и чуть по разному)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через `removeAttribute` попробовать

```
servicesIco.removeAttribute("src"); // Если в servicesIco объект img
```

Comment: Блин, сидел примерно 1 час и вот сам нашёл.

И сразу же вы написали)

Хотел уже закрывать вопрос и сам отвечать)